# Use First() and Repeat() without restarting whole stream RxJS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I am building a trading bot using `RxJS`. For that i have to convert ticker data from a socket connection to candles that is getting emitted every `x` seconds.

I created the `socketObservable` like this

```
const subscribeObservable = Observable.fromEventPattern(h => bittrex.websockets.subscribe(['USDT-BTC'], h))
const clientCallBackObservable = Observable.fromEventPattern(h => bittrex.websockets.client(h))

const socketObservable = clientCallBackObservable
  .flatMap(() => subscribeObservable)
  .filter(subscribtionData => subscribtionData && subscribtionData.M === 'updateExchangeState')
  .flatMap(exchangeState => Observable.from(exchangeState.A))
  .filter(marketData => marketData.Fills.length > 0)
  .map(marketData => marketData && marketData.Fills)
```

Which works fine - when i connect to the client i `flatMap` to the subscription connection.

Then i have the `candleObservable` that is causing problems

```
export const candleObservable = (promise, timeFrame = TIME_FRAME) =>
  promise
    .scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr])
    .skipWhile(exchangeData => dateDifferenceInSeconds(exchangeData) < timeFrame)
    // take first after skipping
    .first()
    // first will complete the stream, so we repeat it
    .repeat()
    // we create candle data from the timeFrame array
    .map(fillsData => createCandle(fillsData))
    // accumulate candles
    .scan((acc, curr) => [...[acc], curr])
```

What i am trying to achieve is to accumulate data until i have for a full candle that can be `x` seconds. Then i would like to take that emit and reset the scan function so i start for a new candle. Then i create the candle and accumulate it in another scan.

My problem is that when i call `repeat()` my `socketObservable` also gets called again. I do not know if this causes any overhead with the `node-bittrex-api` but i would like to avoid it.

I have tried putting the accumulating candle part in a flatMap or similar but couldn't get anyt of that to work.

Do you know how i can avoid to `repeat()` the whole stream or another way of make candles where i can accumulate and then reset the accumulator after first emit?

Comment: Is it possible to simplify the question? Only the minimum neccesary operators and without domain specific stuff like candles.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described it sounds like you have an observable you want to cut up into buckets of some kind based on some condition. In general, the reduction of a stream to another stream with fewer elements (without filtering) is referred to as "backpressure". In your specific case, it sounds like the backpressure operator you'd be interested in is `buffer`. The `buffer` operator can accept an observable as an argument that functions as a "closing selector", i.e. emissions in this observable can be used to regulate when you tie off one buffer and start a new one.

I'd suggest replacing your `scan`, `skipWhile`, `first`, and `repeat` with a `buffer` call, passing in a closing selector that will yield a value when your "TIME_FRAME" expires. This should be easy to express as an observable either using `timer` (in the case of a fixed amount) or a debounced version of the driving stream (if you want to stop when there's a pause in the data). If your buffer is strictly time-based, there's even a specialization of `buffer` called `bufferTime` that handles this. Because you'll wind up with an observable of arrays (rather than raw values), you'll likely want to replace your final `scan` with a regular array `reduce`.

It's hard to give concrete code without a simpler example to work with. I'd urge you to consult the sample code for the various backpressure operators to see if you can find something similar to what you're attempting to achieve.